# UI component add text field for mass action in grid issue

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, massaction

This is my ui component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="create_barcode">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">create_barcode</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create Barcode(s)</item>
<!--                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor_product_barcode/product/massCreateBarcode"/>-->
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ProductBarcode\Ui\Component\Catalog\Product\MassAction\Barcode</argument>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">vendor_product_barcode/product/massCreateBarcode</item>
                        <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">no_of_printing</item>
                    </argument>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

and the content of the Barcode class:

```
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
class Barcode extends  \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    protected $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

}
```

My goal is to add an input field text with a button for my Create barcode option item. And the value of that input field must be parsed to a controller. So far I achieved this:

[image]

I'm not sure, how can i add inside of that submenu an input type text with a button. So any advice are  welcome. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

**record_list.xml**

```
  <container name="listing_top">
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">record_list.record_list.records_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="create_barcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">create_barcode</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create Barcode(s)</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <type>create_barcode</type>
                <label translate="true">Create Barcode(s)</label>
                <actions class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction\CreateBarcode"/>
            </settings>
        </action>
    </massaction>
  </container>
```

add this code in di.xml

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<type name="VendoreName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction\CreateBarcode">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">RouteName/ContorllerName/masscreatebarcode</item>
            <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">no_of_printing</item>
            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translatable="true">Create Barcode(s)</item>
                <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translatable="true">Are you sure to create selected record barcode?</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Ui/Component/MassAction**

**CreateBarcode.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\MassAction;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\JsonSerializable;

class CreateBarcode implements JsonSerializable
{

    protected $options;
    protected $data;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    protected $urlPath;
    protected $paramName;
    protected $additionalData = [];

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        if ($this->options === null) {
            $options = [
                [
                    "value" => "0",
                    "label" => ('Barcode - 1'),
                ],
                [
                    "value" => "1",
                    "label" => ('Barcode - 2'),
                ],
                [
                    "value" => "2",
                    "label" => ('Barcode - 3'),
                ],
                [
                    "value" => "3",
                    "label" => ('Barcode - 4'),
                ],
            ];
            $this->prepareData();
            foreach ($options as $optionCode) {
                $this->options[$optionCode['value']] = [
                    'type' => 'status_' . $optionCode['value'],
                    'label' => $optionCode['label'],
                ];

                if ($this->urlPath && $this->paramName) {
                    $this->options[$optionCode['value']]['url'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        $this->urlPath,
                        [$this->paramName => $optionCode['value']]
                    );
                }

                $this->options[$optionCode['value']] = array_merge_recursive(
                    $this->options[$optionCode['value']],
                    $this->additionalData
                );
            }
            $this->options = array_values($this->options);
        }
        return $this->options;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare addition data for subactions
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareData()
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'urlPath':
                    $this->urlPath = $value;
                    break;
                case 'paramName':
                    $this->paramName = $value;
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->additionalData[$key] = $value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Adminhtml/ControllerName**

**MassCreateBarcode.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\ControllerName;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

class MassCreateBarcode extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $filter;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->filter = $filter;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $selectedAppsid = $this->getRequest()->getParams('no_of_printing');
        print_r($selectedAppsid);
        exit();
        /*
                write your logic for create barcode

        */

    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thnx for helping me out. It works , but this is not what i want to achieve. If you check my image and my description, it says: "inside of that submenu an input type text with a button" .   So Instead of those Barcodes options, I would like to have a input type text and a button. So the user will choose the value for `no_of_printing`. Not sure If I make myself clear, otherwise please let me know and thnx again for your help :)

Comment: so any idea how to approach this ? with my proposal ? Or even adding `prompt widget` - js , would be enough

Comment: i never use this type of widget but my suggestion is you have unique value for each row. so simple you can add these unique to create unique barcode.

Comment: and you can give option create barcode from your give value like name type id etc.

Comment: my goal is to create copies :) of a generated barcode. so if I add 10 and select 2 products. I will have 10 copies of each generated barcode .  Not sure how can i achieve this with options (dropdowns)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106099/discussion-between-msquare-and-attila-naghi).